# python seaborn to reset back to the matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, marker, seaborn

I'm using seaborn version o.4 and matplotlib version 1.42
I have a chart displays both line and marker through simple plot command eg.

```
plt.plot([1,5,3,8,4],'-bo');
```

Due to a potential bug (https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/344), after import seaborn, same code shows line only without marker.

```
import seaborn as sb 
plt.plot([1,5,3,8,4],'-bo');
```

So my question is: after import seaborn, Is there a way to reset all the parameters back to original?

Answer (score 53):

Yes, call [`seaborn.reset_orig`](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.reset_orig.html#seaborn.reset_orig).

Comment: This sort-of works, but plots made after `import seaborn` and `seaborn.reset_orig()` still look quite different to plots made before these lines. Is there a way to get rid of all seaborn effects, as if it had never been imported?

Answer (score 40):

None of these solutions worked for me (Python 3.x, Jupyter).
What worked was `matplotlib.rc_file_defaults()`

See the documentation here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.rc_file_defaults

Comment: This solution worked for me with Python 3. `seaborn.reset_orig` did not work.

Comment: The correct link is now https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.rc_file_defaults

Answer (score 11):

To refresh Matplotlib's configuration side effects often encountered with Seaborn:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
```

Run this:

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(mpl); importlib.reload(plt); importlib.reload(sns)
```

For old Python2 code:

```
import imp
imp.reload(mpl); imp.reload(plt); imp.reload(sns)
```

Note: None of the following correctly restores the state of matplotlib:

- sns.reset_orig()
- sns.reset_defaults()
- mpl.rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsDefault)

Comment: `Importlib` imports fine, but when I try using `reload` I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'reload'`. Is this only available in Python 3.x?

Comment: doh, updated for Python 2:  import imp;  imp.reload(somemodule)

Comment: For anyone reading this in the near future: I tried this with several different versions of matplotlib and seaborn inside Jupyter and could not get it to work, I don't think this is a general solution (maybe it used to be).

Answer (score 6):

In my case I was searching to reset the plot sizes of the output specifically when I changed using the `rc` attribute used the following code to reset to default size `sns.reset_defaults()` (where sns is seaborn).

Answer (score 5):

You can save the `rcParams` you want, before changing the style with seaborn (note that seaborn no longer changes the `rcParams` upon import):

```
import matplotlib as mpl

my_params = mpl.rcParams

# apply some change to the rcparams here

mpl.rcParams.update(my_params)
```

Note that both these

```
mpl.rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsOrig)
mpl.rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsDefault)
```

restores *almost* all `rcParams` to their default value. The few that will be different can easily be viewed by (I ran this in a Jupyter Notebook):

```
# Differences between current params and `Default`
for key in mpl.rcParamsDefault:
    if not mpl.rcParamsDefault[key] == mpl.rcParams[key]:
        print(key, mpl.rcParamsDefault[key], mpl.rcParams[key])

## backend agg module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline
## figure.dpi 100.0 72.0
## figure.edgecolor w (1, 1, 1, 0)
## figure.facecolor w (1, 1, 1, 0)
## figure.figsize [6.4, 4.8] [6.0, 4.0]
## figure.subplot.bottom 0.11 0.125
```

and

```
# Differences between `Default` and `Orig`
for key in mpl.rcParamsDefault:
    if not mpl.rcParamsDefault[key] == mpl.rcParamsOrig[key]:
        print(key, mpl.rcParamsDefault[key], mpl.rcParamsOrig[key])

## backend agg Qt5Agg
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set them back to default by doing:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsDefault)
```

Also, check [this post](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.11-settings-and-stylesheets.html) from Jake VanderPlas to learn more about customizing matplotlib.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -4):

One can simply call the `seaborn.set()` function, with no function parameters, see `[seaborn tutorial][1]`.

Comment: This does nothing

Comment: The solution I provided with above was working at the time I replied. No need to down vote me.