# Use seaborn and matplotlib defaults in same ipython notebook

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, seaborn

I am trying to use both seaborn and matplotlib defaults to create plots in an ipython notebook, each plot with it's own default mpl or sns style. I have followed the instructions outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25393936/3639023) question, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26899310/3639023) one, however they don't quite do what I need.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16])
```

[image]

```
import seaborn as sns
plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16])
```

[image]

```
sns.reset_orig()
plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16])
```

[image]

The last plot saves without the grey border, however the size is still different than the original. And the inline display is not the same as the original. Ideally I would like to be able to set the style on a per plot basis. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: You could try importing `seaborn.apionly` and then using context managers to control the style for individual plots. I'm not sure why reseting to the matplotlib "orig" params doesn't work in the notebook.

Comment: Is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413185/how-to-recover-matplotlib-defaults-after-setting-stylesheet one helpful?